# How to have trainable weights for multiple losses?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I have a weighted loss consisting multiple losses for training my model.

```
loss = w1 * loss1 + w2 * loss2 + w3 * loss3
loss.backward()
```

Is there any possible way to make w1, w2 and w3 learnable parameters? I tried making initializing them using `self.w1 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.33), requires_grad=True)` inside the model, but after one iteration it's value is becoming `nan`.

There are other issues to consider when we want to make the weights learnable such as, whats stopping them from going to zero or even going negative in order to make loss zero, how would we ensure that the weights don't concentrate on just one loss.

Is there a way to have these weights learnable rather than having hand-tuned weights?

Comment: You do not need to hand-tune them but you cannot learn them during the training. You train to minimize the less, similar to regularization, if you allow the model to reduce the loss weights it will just do that. Smaller weights -> smaller loss. You would need some constraints but they are also not easy, i.e. the model tries to reduce the weight of the largest lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have loss weights be learned within the same process. The weights will go to zero (or even negative). Loss weights are hyperparameters that must be set externally.

If you want a learning process to set the loss weights, it has to be an outer loop around your model training process.

You can research loss weighting in multitask learning to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the idea of Gradient Reversal layer to train the weight of losses, but in general I think you should rescale the loss and apply some constraints to the weights (sigmoid, softmax, ...)